# CXF: Cannot create Crypto class null

Tags: java, grails, cxf

When I make a call to any CXF endpoint, I receive this fault. What caused the `null` class?

```
Exception javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot create Crypto class null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    [...]
```

The endpoint is valid and Wireshark indicates that no connection to the server has been made. This error must be related to the connection initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `ws-security.encryption.properties`/`ws-security.signature.properties` file had an incorrect path for `org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file` defined.

I am still researching, but it appears that this location is detected differently in the new folder structure we are upgrading to for Grails 3. Since this error does not appear on any other sites, I thought a hint should be made available to others.